# Is there a canonical question telling people why they should use SQL parameters?

Tags: discussion, questions, canonical

Often in the [.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.net) questions when people have a question about NullReferenceExceptions we direct them to the question [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Is there similar type question we can direct people to about not using string concatenation in building up SQL queries and instead to use parameters to pass in their values?

Comment: Sure, [xkcd already provided one](http://xkcd.com/327/).  Won't stop them of course.

Comment: @HansPassant - The irony is that cartoon has probably made a more positive impact on developers than the actual documentation and all of the angry DB Admins who witness these things.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: I use this for `vb.net` questions: [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå Can you post that comment as an answer, I would like to upvote that.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: 113 answers, 28 of those still visible. Are you sure you locked that early enough?

Comment: I did some searching based on the most popular language tags on SO, but I could not find any good canonical Q/As other than the two listed here (for PHP and VB.NET).  So I have started a list answer for everyone to contribute.  It does seem that some more canonical Q/As are needed (especially for Java and JavaScript).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

List of canonical Q/As for SQL injection and parameters based on the most popular language tags.  If a good canonical Q/A has not been identified, candidates and source material is listed instead.

*Note: Feel free to make appropriate updates to this list.*

---

**Language Neutral:** [How can I explain SQL injection without technical jargon?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/25684/how-can-i-explain-sql-injection-without-technical-jargon)

**C#:** (Proposed): [ASP.NET, C# How to Pass a StringQuery to a custom SQL Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35614173/asp-net-c-sharp-how-to-pass-a-stringquery-to-a-custom-sql-command/35615046#35615046) (Links to this discussion and others mentioned in it)

- [Avoiding SQL injection without parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/910465/avoiding-sql-injection-without-parameters)
- [SQL injection on INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681583/sql-injection-on-insert)

**C++:** *None Identified*

- [Preventing SQL injection in C++ OTL, DTL, or SOCI libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118661/preventing-sql-injection-in-c-otl-dtl-or-soci-libraries)

**Java:** *None Identified*

- [Java - escape string to prevent SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812891/java-escape-string-to-prevent-sql-injection)
- [Stop sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10361510/stop-sql-injection)
- [Avoiding SQL injection in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17391720/avoiding-sql-injection-in-java)
- [How does a PreparedStatement avoid or prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1582161/how-does-a-preparedstatement-avoid-or-prevent-sql-injection)
- [how to prevent SQL Injection in JSP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6272861/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-jsp)
- [Prevent SQL injection attacks in a Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9516625/prevent-sql-injection-attacks-in-a-java-program)

**JavaScript:** *None Identified*

- [How to avoid SQL injection in a javascript text field?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836871/how-to-avoid-sql-injection-in-a-javascript-text-field)
- [sql injection - how to sanitize program generated sql clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7291630/sql-injection-how-to-sanitize-program-generated-sql-clause)

**PHP:** [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

**Python:** *None Identified*

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1973/what-is-the-best-way-to-avoid-sql-injection-attacks

**VB.NET:** [How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)

Comment: Why isn't this list included in the SQL et all tags wiki?

Comment: Do you think that would be a useful place to list the canonical Q/As?

Comment: Yep............. that should be the place.

Answer (score 5):

I use the following link for questions tagged with `vb.net`:

[How do I create a parameterized SQL query? Why Should I?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/542510/how-do-i-create-a-parameterized-sql-query-why-should-i)